# How to connect Arduino device to Linux?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, linux

I wrote Arduino sketch and it works. It waits for a command and answers text on response.

[image]

Simultaneously, I can't get any response with command line tools.

For example, I have the following code to get temperature:

```
#!/bin/bash
tty=/dev/ttyUSB0
exec 4<$tty 5>$tty
stty -F $tty cs8 9600 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts
#stty -F $tty 9600 -echo
#printf "temp\n" >&5
echo temp >&5
read reply <&4
echo "$reply"
#tail -n 1 - <&4
```

It returns empty or hang under different circumstances.

Also, if I run built-in `Serial Monitor`, I can see responses on command lines like:

```
echo temp > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But I see nothing with commands like `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I really want to say using Linux is where you going wrong, but that would be childish. :)  I'm not sure if I read it right, but are you trying to connect two apps to the same console port?  I wouldn't expect that to work, but I only use Windows, does that work on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Add the flag `-hupcl` to your `stty` command.  That will disable the assertion of DTR which is resetting the board.

```
 hupcl (-hupcl)
             Stop asserting modem control (do not stop asserting modem
             control) on last close.
```

The first time it is run there will be a reset, since setting that flag entails opening the port, which causes a reset.  So you need to add a delay long enough to get past the bootloader - minimum 2 seconds, best make it 3.

You can do that with the `sleep` command: `sleep 3`

Note that you now won't be able to upload a new sketch since you have disabled the auto-reset feature that allows you to enter the bootloader, so before uploading a new sketch you need to turn the reset back on with

```
stty -F $tty hupcl
```

If you don't disable the reset then every operation in your script that opens and then closes the serial port will trigger a reset of the board.  So in summary try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tty=/dev/ttyUSB0
stty -F $tty cs8 9600 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts -hupcl
sleep 3
echo temp >$tty
read reply <$tty
echo "$reply"
stty -F $tty hupcl
```

Comment: I was wishing to use reset feature. Why doesn't it work with it?

Comment: In that case leave the stty as it is, but just add the three second delay so it can get past the bootloader before you send your request.

Comment: I was waiting long enough with `tail -f`, also I was observing directly, that Serial Monitor does see the output, while `tail -f` does not.

Comment: You can't read the data with two things at once - only one thing will get it.  Also you have to wait *before sending "temp"* otherwise it just won't ever get it.

Comment: By the way, what are exact conditions for resetting? I have 3 commands in the script, touching the port: `stty`, `echo` and `read`. Will it reset 3 times or only one, how to know?

Comment: One more thing: every operation you perform from your shell script will trigger a new reset.  You should disable reset at the beginning (which will make it reset once) then enable it again afterwards.

Comment: As it happens I was answering that at the same time as you asked it - the same thought occurred to me ;)

Comment: Why can I see the answers with `Serial Monitor`? Why doesn't it reset then?

Comment: While it is open it is open - it's only when the last file descriptor is closed that it resets the board. While the serial monitor is open there will always be an active file descriptor.

Comment: Isn't it possible with shell script to keep port opened?

Comment: Not really, no.  It executes a series of distinct commands with little to no state between them.  You want to use Perl or Python or something if you want to do that kind of thing.  I can recommend Device::SerialPort in perl, and people do keep trying to use PySerial

Comment: Okay, but why doesn't `read` command wait until it get something? Why should I make explicit delay? Why can't I initiate reset, then wait for ANYTHING with `read`, then read it, then exit?

Comment: You are sending first to initiate a read from what I understand. It's that initial write (echo) that must be delayed.

Comment: PySerial is not too bad to use if one wants to transfer text. What is somewhat more problematic, as it goes against the grain of Python, is to do byte-oriented data transfer, but it's not impossible, it requires a bit of juggling.

Comment: @IgorStoppa That's why I say "try and use it" ;)  Personally I do it all in pure C...

Comment: @Majenko: it depends on the overall language you want to use in a project ... using multiple languages is not necessarily the kindest act toward who will read it later on :-)   - anyway, it's not that long/complicated: https://github.com/01org-AutomatedFlasherTester/pem/blob/master/src/mappedbuffer.py

Comment: @IgorStoppa Urgh - I feel dirty now. I need to go and scrub my eyeballs.

Comment: @Majenko you mean, that no synchronization or buffering occur? Computer does not feel that Arduino is not on and just blindly send bits, which turn lost?

Comment: @Dims The computer has no concept of what an Arduino is.  When you send data the Arduino receives it.  If the Arduino is in the bootloader, which it is for 2 seconds after reboot, then the bootloader receives the text, not your sketch.  Only once the bootloader is finished with will any text sent to the Arduino make it to your sketch.

Comment: @Majenko see my separate question on it: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/doesnt-arduino-reports-dsr-data-set-ready-correctly 
I agree, that computer has no concept of Arduino. But computer should has concept of obeying the protocol.

Comment: @Majenko: it's portable (as in: works without recompiling) and doesn't require using _also_ perl (no, writing everything in perl was not an option and anyway I would have not liked it)

Comment: @Dims The Arduino *is* ready to receive the moment the reset is performed. It's just *your sketch* that isn't ready to receive because *the Arduino is busy doing other things first for 2 seconds **before** your sketch is run*